# React rerender full tree of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I have a component:

```js
export const Filters: FC = observer(() => (
    <div className={`filters ${viewModel.isDragged ? 'filters--dragged' : ''} ${!viewModel.isOpened ? 'filters--collapsed' : ''}`}
         style={viewModel.position}>
        <FiltersHeader/>
        <FiltersBody/>
    </div>
));
```

This component is decorated with `observer` from `mobx-react-lite`. Field `position` is decorated with `@observable` decorator from `mobx` package. `position` is consist of field `left: number` and `top: number`.

I want to drag this component. And to achieve it I reinisialize `position` when user triggers `mousemove`.

The problem is `<FiltersHeader/>` and `<FiltersBody/>` not small components, it takes a while to render them. And each time I change `viewModel.position` React rerender entire tree. Not only FiltersHeader and FiltersBody, also their children and their children, etc.

Why does React do that? I mean, FiltersHeader has no properties. React should not rerender the component again if its properties did not change. Or should it?

---

This code works the same

```js
export const Filters: FC = () => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(viewModel.position);
    useEffect(() => {
        reaction(() => viewModel.position, value => setPosition(value));
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className={`filters ${viewModel.isDragged ? 'filters--dragged' : ''} ${!viewModel.isOpened ? 'filters--collapsed' : ''}`}
             style={position}>
            <FiltersHeader/>
            <FiltersBody/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Function componets always rerender, it is up to you to control the computational heavy parts of the components with hooks so they don't need to be recalculated. If you really want your function components to act like class components you can wrap them in React.memo HOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenter said, React does not apply optimizations by default, so every child component will rerender (even if it has no props) when parent component does.

You can wrap them in `React.memo` or actually wrap in `observer` too, because it also applies `memo` automatically.